# Why classes that don't extends other classes must extend from traits? (with doesn't work)

Tags: scala, traits

i'm starting with Scala and i found this a little weird. In java i could do something like this:

```
interface Foo{}

public class Bar implements Foo{}
```

I'm trying to do something similar with Scala, but it doesn't work:

```
trait Foo;
class Bar with Foo; // This doesn't work!
```

I have to use the "extends" keyword:

```
class Bar extends Foo; // This works OK!
```

Now, it's fine, but it's not what i wanted.

Another thing weird i noted is that given every class in Scala extends from AnyRef (see this image from scala-lang.org: http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/images/classhierarchy.png) i can do this:

```
class Bar extends AnyRef with Foo; // This works too!
```

So, what am i missing? Doesn't have sense to use a trait without extending it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First note that the extends/implements difference tells nothing to the compiler than it would not know. I don't mean that it is bad, just that the language could have done otherwise. In C#, you write `class A : B, C, D` instead of both `class A extends B implements C, D` and `class A implements B, C, D`. So you can just think that Scala's `extends` is like the colon and `with` like the comma.

Yet, in the old times, it used to be `class Bar with Foo`. It changed when Scala went 2.0 back in 2006. See [the change history](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/43).

I think I remember (not sure) that the reason was simply that `class Bar with Foo` does not read well.

In Scala, `A with B` is the intersection of types `A` and `B`. An object is of type `A with B` if it is both of type `A` and of type `B`. So `class A extends B with C` may be read `class A` extends the type `B with C`. No such thing with `class A with B`.

Answer (score 10):

If you are coming from Java, it can sound strange at first (it was the same for me), but actually now I find it's more regular syntax then Java's, where I need to explicitly say whether I want to `implement` or `extend` other class/interface. But I think it's more question of the personal taste.

It does not actually matter whether you are saying `extends` or `implements`. They both represent the same kind of relationship between two things: **is a** (in contrast to delegation and composition, which represent **has a** relationship). Here, for instance, you can find some more information about it:

http://www.javacamp.org/moreclasses/oop/oop5.html

Just try to replace `extends`, `implements`, `with` with `is a` and it becomes more clear.

In Scala you also have other variations of `is a` relation. For example **self types**:

```
trait Bar {
   self: Foo =>
   // ...
}
```

With this you are saying, that `Bar` does not extends/implements `Foo` directly, but all other classes, that want to extend `Bar` should also extend `Foo`.

**Self types** can allow interesting things. For example two classes/traits that depend on each other:

```
class Bar extends Foo {
    def sayHello(name: String) = println("Hello, " + name)

    greet()
}

trait Foo {
    this: Bar =>

    def greet() = sayHello("User")
}

new Bar() // prints: Hello, User
```

Comment: see also http://www.levinotik.com/2012/09/14/scala-abstract-classes-traits-and-self-types/

Comment: this is an interesting answer, especially the "self types" part. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

[Programming in Scala (2nd ed)](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala) discusses traits in Chapter 12.  It notes with regards to `extends`:

> You can use the extends keyword to mix in a trait; in that case you
>   implicitly inherit the trait’s superclass. For instance, in Listing 12.2, class
>   `Frog` subclasses `AnyRef` (the superclass of `Philosophical`) and mixes in
>   `Philosophical`.

(Here, `Philosophical` is a trait.)

So, your reasoning is exactly correct.

On the subject of `AnyRef`, you should read about the [Scala class hierarchy](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/scalas-hierarchy.html) and [top types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_type). (`AnyRef` is not the top type but it is pretty close.)

Comment: I have that book! Why did i miss it? Thank you @Emil